# Java - get windows logged user

Tags: java, windows

I'm logged in to windows 10 with a regular user (no admin privileges). I run my java application with admin privileges, but I need to get the normal logged-in user   path (that's unprivileged) at runtime. System.getProperty ("user.home") only returns me the admin user path. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"user.home"` to `"user.name"`. However, if you run the program as Administrator that is what it will return.

Comment: that's just it. I'm running my program as an administrator, but would like to get the primary user name. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *I'm running my program as an administrator, but would like to get the primary user name. Is there a way to do this?* Don't run your program as administrator. Otherwise, **no**. Because the user running the program (when you run the program as administrator) **is** administrator.